# Node.js Cannot find module 'tcp'

Tags: javascript, node.js, tcp, module

node is crashing at the following line:

```
var tcp = require('tcp'),
```

error text:

```
node.js:201
    throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'tcp'
at Function._resolveFilename (module.js:334:11)
at Function._load (module.js:279:25)
at Module.require (module.js:357:17)
at require (module.js:368:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\websocket\websocket.js:11:11)

at Module._compile (module.js:432:26)
at Object..js (module.js:450:10)
at Module.load (module.js:351:31)
at Function._load (module.js:310:12)
at Module.require (module.js:357:17)
```

What is the problem? I found the source on the Internet, and the author, and the visitors also can run it...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try `require('net')` instead:

```
$ node
> var tcp = require('tcp');
The 'tcp' module is now called 'net'. Otherwise it should have a similar interface.
> var tcp = require('net');
> $
```

Answer (score 1):

Others are able to run, may be because they are using Node module when 'tcp' was there...

Now its called 'net', but its all the same thing no need of checking..

If you want to cross check for your more information, here are the links:

1.http://nodejs.org/api/net.html

2.https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/net.js