# Node js, module.js: 340 Error: cannot find module 'tcp'

Tags: javascript, node.js

Im new in node js programming, and im working on a program that wants to create a server for a robot company. i have the files for running the server that they sent me. Now the problem is when i run the server its showing the error

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'tcp'

    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Users\Vishnu Mohan\Projects\website\libs\node.websocket.js\lib\redis.js:7:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

so i changed tcp to net (tip from stack overflow) and i run again. now im getting another error

```
    this.conn = new process.tcp.Connection();
                               ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Connection' of undefined

    at Client.connect (D:\Users\Vishnu Mohan\Projects\website\libs\node.websocket.js\lib\redis.js:47:32)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Users\Vishnu Mohan\Projects\website\libs\node.websocket.js\log.js:66:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Users\Vishnu Mohan\Projects\website\libs\node.websocket.js\websocket.js:14:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
```

im using latest version of node v0.10.33

```
var sys = require("sys"), 
    tcp= require("tcp");

Client.prototype.connect = function (callback_on_connect, callback_on_error) {
  var self = this;
  if (this.conn && this.conn.readyState === "open") {
    if (typeof(callback_on_connect) === "function")
      callback_on_connect();
  } else {
    this.conn = new process.tcp.Connection();
    this.conn.addListener("connect", function () {
      this.setEncoding("binary");
      this.setTimeout(0);          // try to stay connected.
      this.setNoDelay();
      if (typeof(callback_on_connect) === "function")
        callback_on_connect();
    });
```

Comment: would you like to post some more of your code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8198612/node-js-cannot-find-module-tcp
does this help?

Comment: @huan feng, i tried that then i got the second error

Comment: @ryanc1256, 
var sys = require("sys"), 
    tcp= require("tcp");

Answer (score 0):

Okay first up 
the module tcp is now called "net" and here is the doc's for them
http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_new_net_socket_options

just by reading the doc's i altered your code...

```
var sys = require("sys"), 
    tcp= require("net");
var port = 80;

Client.prototype.connect = function (callback, error){
    var self = this;
    if (this.conn && this.conn.readyState === "open") {
        if (typeof(callback) === "function")
            callback();
    } else {
        this.conn = new net.Socket();

        this.conn.connect(port, function() {
            this.setEncoding('binary');
            this.setTimeout(0);
            this.setNoDelay();
        });


        this.conn.on('connect', function(){
          console.log('something connected!');
        });

        this.conn.on('error', function(error){
               error();
                console.log(err);
        });
    }
}
```

I haven't tried it yet, but i guess this point's you in the right direction

Comment: Thanks ryanc1256, I will try that... This problem is eating my brain out.